# Different results in query against CTE

Tags: sql-server

This is strictly my lack of complete understanding of CTEs -- kind of just getting started with them. I have the following data:

```
create table tblHolidays
(
    HolidayId int identity(101, 1) Primary Key, HolidayDate datetime
)
go
insert into tblHolidays values
    ('2015-01-10'), ('2015-01-09'), ('2015-01-08'), ('2015-01-07'),
    ('2015-02-19'), ('2015-03-11'), ('2015-04-11')
go
```

and the following code (trying to retrieve the first previous day that is not a holiday):

```
with CTE1 as
(
select  *,
        dateadd(dd, -1, HolidayDate) as PrevDay,
        row_number() over(order by HolidayDate desc) as RN
from    tblHolidays
),
CTE2 as
(
select  *,
        case
            when PrevDay = lead(HolidayDate) over(order by (select null)) 
            then 0 else 1
            --when PrevDay = lead(HolidayDate) over(order by HolidayDate desc) then 0 else 1
        end as Foo
from    CTE1 as C
)
select top 1 PrevDay, HolidayDate from CTE2 where PrevDay < cast('2015-01-10' as datetime) and Foo = 1
```

When executed, I am receiving a variety of results and am not sure why. What I expect is for the output to be is:

```
PrevDay     HolidayDate
2015-01-06  2015-01-07
```

AND, it is for the result set above as initially inserted. However, if I add another record into tblHolidays and set 2015-01-06 as a holiday, thereby wanting to retrieve the previous day of 2015-01-05, I do not get it, I still get the above result.

HOWEVER, if I swap out the column HolidayDate for RN, I do get the correct result! I do not understand that. I know there are other ways to do this, but I truly want to understand why this is behaving the way it is. There is something that I am fundamentally missing with the execution order of CTEs I think.

Comment: Your `LEAD`function is missing an order by column. This will make the `LEAD` behave randomly on each run. You might want to order by `Holyday DESC`. You are getting the day 5 result because you are doing a `TOP 1` at the bottom with no `ORDER BY`. There is no magic with CTEs, they behave as expected and are calculated in order, in this case.

Comment: `order by (select null)` will not give you deterministic behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in this bit of code: `lead(HolidayDate) over(order by (select null))`.
When using windowed function, if you specify `select null` in any clause, query might behave randomly - different results on every run - that's what you are facing right now.

`order by (select null)` - order is physical order of the table, you can get different results every time you run such query.

`partition by (select null)` - no partitioning. It's less dangerous than specyfying `order by (select null)` clause (to be clear - it's not dangerous at all), because result of such query won't be random.

You would have to specify proper `order by` clause, like this:
`lead(HolidayDate) over(order by HolidayDate)`. This will give output as you desire.

Comment: thank you. when you say "less dangerous", is that implying that there still is a risk of getting back undesired results?

Comment: @Michael No, it's not dangerous as well, I modified answer. Also, accept it if it 
helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another approach.

Instead of setting a single holidays day use periods. Next udf inline function simulates a periods table:

```
-- holidays periods
create function dbo.getHolidays()
returns table
as
return
(
    with rst as
    (
        select HolidayDate,
               iif(lag(HolidayDate) over (order by HolidayDate) = dateadd(dd, -1, HolidayDate), null, 1) reset
        from   tblHolidays
    ), g as
    (
        select HolidayDate, 
               count(reset) over (order by HolidayDate) as grp
        from   rst
    )
    select min(HolidayDate) as StartDate, max(HolidayDate) as EndDate
    from   g
    group by grp
);
```

It returns:

```
select * from dbo.getHolidays();
GO

StartDate           | EndDate            
:------------------ | :------------------
06/01/2015 00:00:00 | 10/01/2015 00:00:00
19/02/2015 00:00:00 | 19/02/2015 00:00:00
11/03/2015 00:00:00 | 11/03/2015 00:00:00
11/04/2015 00:00:00 | 11/04/2015 00:00:00
```

Now you can check if some date belongs to some holidays period easily in this way:

```
declare @dateSearch datetime;
set @dateSearch = '20150110'

select * 
from   dbo.getHolidays()
where  @dateSearch >= startDate 
and    @dateSearch <= endDate;
GO

StartDate           | EndDate            
:------------------ | :------------------
06/01/2015 00:00:00 | 10/01/2015 00:00:00
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=03fd374bff528494cb6ea092af75eb07)*